# How to use list of value in where clause

Tags: hibernate

I am using hibernate3 in my java application. I have to find the list of value from oracle using hibernate. So my query is like

Ex:

```
List<TestClass> selectedpins =DAO.findAll(from register where pin in (list))
```

This list contains list of ids(around 3000 values). Due to performance issue i am not able to use iterator. So kindly let me know how to use this list of value in this query.

Is it possible in hibernate3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
session
  .createQuery("select pins from register where pin in (:list)")
  .setParameterList("list", pinIds)
  .getResultList();
```

Comment: Can i use the below code in hibernate3                                         public static List<LoginPin> getduplicatePins(List generatedPins) {
  return Dao.findAll("select pin from LoginPin where pin in (?)",generatedPins);
 
 }

Comment: I am getting below error if i am using the above code.==>Errro Occured:org.hibernate.QueryException: Not all named parameters have been set: [generatedPins] [select pin from LoginPin where pin in (:generatedPins)]
 at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractQueryImpl.verifyParameters(AbstractQueryImpl.java:291)

Comment: You are providing parameters to the Dao method. In there you should be doing : List<Pins> findAll(List<Object> pinIds) { //In here place the query I stated earlier }

Comment: @RajaShanmugam - there was a typo in the query, a ';' in place of '.' after the createQuery(). Corrected.

Comment: Don't forget that the in-list size is limited. Too what depends or DB vendor (I believe oracle has a limit of 1000).